# Can validation drop down text be different from resulting value in cell?

Tags: validation, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to concoct a creative way for a Google Sheets cell to provide a drop down menu which contains more text than the resulting cell value after the user makes a selection.

My intent is that the text in the drop down be more descriptive than the resulting cell value.

For example, I want the drop down to provide options like this:

- **None: No data**
- **Limited: Up to 10% of data known**
- **Some: Up to 50% of of data known**
- **Significant: Up to 75% of data known**
- **Satisfactory: Up to 99% of data known**
- **Full: 100% of data known**

But after a selection is made, for the cell to contain only `None`, `Limited`, `Some`, `Significant`, `Satisfactory` or `Full`.

I greatly prefer an "in-place" drop down menu to popping a custom HTML dialog to collect this information, but can't get any traction at all, so I'm hoping someone has a technique to share, or even a strategy to suggest.

Comment: It sounds like a great idea but I don't think it's currently possible. A cell or (or a range of cells) can't have multiple data validations or 'display values'. The shortened cell values would violate their own validation rule and show input errors. I also can't see how one can force inputs to partially match the dropdown items

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do that, but you could put your information in a note on the cell.